# ng-repeat not showing anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I expect to push new row for user to put in extra info but I'm stuck at generate the first row

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
<input type="text" placeholder="name"><input type="tel" placeholder="tel">
</div>

$scope.rows = {
   '1':1
};

}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qNPYKwdRPNXRrqphEfdz?p=preview

Comment: here is updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/mO2MXrNUUnAvAd0Ns4jP?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have to remove `ng-controller="personController"` from the html tag.

AngularJS is searching for that controller, but it doesn't exist, giving an error on the console.

`Updated plunker`: http://plnkr.co/edit/N14qOlvzPF8eIuPj1I4U?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

In your plunker the html has a reference to a controller that doesn't exist.

Replace:

```
<html ng-app ng-controller="personController">
```

With:

```
<html ng-app>
```

In your controller you put a json object on scope

```
$scope.rows = {'1':1};
```

I suggest using a JSON array instead:

```
$scope.rows = [
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}]
```

Regards Ian

Answer (score 0):

You have `ng-controller="personController"` but no implementation for that controller.